# Secure a QGIS layer with password and protection from copy-pasting

Tags: qgis, security, password

In a project we want to share a geographic layer, but we want to avoid that this data can be accessed without password and easily copied & pasted (and of course can't be edited). The polygons should only be viewed in QGIS with their IDs visible.

Maybe a passworded WFS or WMS does the trick? If so, can you make it without a server?

Does anyone have experience securing layer like this and have any advice?

Answer (score 10):

QGIS runs on the user's computer. If QGIS can show the data, then the user can read the data. If the user can read the data, then the user can copy the data.

A WFS, with or "without a server" (no sure what that means) doesn't help - the data still has to go to QGIS, so the user still needs to read it, so the user can still copy it.

A WMS server might help *slightly* since then QGIS is only getting *images*, which are drawn by the WMS server from the vector data. Assuming you don't want the users to get the vector data, then this works, although the vector data can still be recovered to some degree of accuracy by polygonising the raster output from the WMS.

Note this only works for a remote *server* WMS which the user does not have access to. If you distribute the data with a local server then the user must have access to the data itself too.

Any other form of "encryption" for controlling the viewing of local data is merely "obfuscation", since at some point QGIS has to "decrypt" the data for display, and QGIS is being run by the user, so the user must have the decryption keys.